# An inequality for Ext

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, inequalities

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}$Consider the following statement for a $K$-algebra $A$:
$\dim(\Ext^1 (M, N )) \ge \min( \dim(\Ext^1(M, M )), \dim(\Ext^1 (N, N )) ),$
for all finite dimensional indecomposable $A$-modules $M$, $N$.

The truth of this inequality has some nice consequences/corollaries.

> Question: Is there a nice class of (finite dimensional) algebras $A$ where this inequality holds (maybe for a special class of modules only)? In particular, does this inequality always hold for representation-finite string algebras?

In joint work with Apolonia Gottwald, we proved that the inequality holds for Nakayama algebras, but it feels like it might hold in much larger generality.

Answer (score 1):

(This should probably be a comment but I can't comment yet)

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}$For a class of modules where this inequality holds, one can consider directing modules. Then this inequality holds trivially, since a directing indecomposable module $M$ satisfies $\Ext_A^j(M,M)=0$ for all $j>0$, see Proposition IX.1.4 in [Assem, Simson and Skowroński - Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1: Techniques of Representation Theory](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511614309).

For a class of algebras, one may then consider representation-directed algebras which are algebras where every indecomposable module is directing.